# Flink Task Manager Keep Restarting

Tags: apache-flink

I've just upgraded my flink version to 1.11.2 and run flink using docker container

I have total RAM 55Gb,CPU 32 core and running 1 JM 1 TM in that server
I have 6 flink jobs running using state (1 job have around 4-15Gb state size)

I have set this to flink-conf yaml:

> jobmanager.memory.process.size: 8192m
> taskmanager.memory.process.size: 40960m
> taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots:32
> state.backend: rocksdb
> state.checkpoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/state_dir/backend
> state.savepoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/state_dir/savepoint
> state.backend.local-recovery: true

I saw my task manager keep restarting every 6 hours (I assume I'm running out of memory)
How to handle this? Is there any other configs I neeed to set in my flink-conf.yaml to tune the performance and avoid OOM?

[This is my grafana metrics showing JM and TM memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6S6x.png)

And I have tune some config:

> state.backend.incremental: true
> state.backend.rocksdb.timer-service.factory:heap 
> state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed: true
> state.backend.rocksdb.memory.write-buffer-ratio:0.7

but still no luck

This is my error log for each job, I assume bcs of OOM, the job is down or stuck and try to create new task slot:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: No pooled slot available and request to ResourceManager for new slot failed
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:607)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl.slotRequestToResourceManagerFailed(SlotPoolImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl.lambda$requestSlotFromResourceManager$1(SlotPoolImpl.java:348)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:402)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:195)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: No pooled slot available and request to ResourceManager for new slot failed
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.ResourceManagerException: Could not fulfill slot request 1d147d376eb21fda4a56014bf5a75874.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl.registerSlotRequest(SlotManagerImpl.java:391)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.requestSlot(ResourceManager.java:457)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor159.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:199)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.UnfulfillableSlotRequestException: Could not fulfill slot request 1d147d376eb21fda4a56014bf5a75874. Requested resource profile (ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}) is unfulfillable.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl.lambda$fulfillPendingSlotRequestWithPendingTaskManagerSlot$11(SlotManagerImpl.java:882)
    at org.apache.flink.util.OptionalConsumer.ifNotPresent(OptionalConsumer.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl.fulfillPendingSlotRequestWithPendingTaskManagerSlot(SlotManagerImpl.java:878)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl.lambda$internalRequestSlot$9(SlotManagerImpl.java:865)
    at org.apache.flink.util.OptionalConsumer.ifNotPresent(OptionalConsumer.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl.internalRequestSlot(SlotManagerImpl.java:865)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl.registerSlotRequest(SlotManagerImpl.java:386)
    ... 26 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Which state backend are you using? Is the TM heap growing in size over time? If it was running stably before the upgrade, how was it configured then?

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, This is my state backend config:
state.backend: rocksdb
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/state_dir/backend
state.savepoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/state_dir/savepoint
state.backend.incremental: false
state.backend.rocksdb.timer-service.factory: rocksdb
state.backend.local-recovery: true

Previously I use 1.9 version also have the same problem that's why I upgrade the flink version since I read the article that in version 1.11 has better memory management for state backend

Comment: I suggest reading https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html#tuning-rocksdb, if you haven't already. But I wouldn't expect RocksDB to cause of an OOM problem. I would look in the logs to verify why the TM is restarting, and look at the metrics to see what resource(s) are being depleted.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Do you have any mail address? I can send the  metrics using grafana and also the log file

Comment: You could add screenshots of the metrics to your question. For the logs, you could use something like pastebin, or look through them and extract the relevant bits to share as part of your question.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, I've attached more information. Need your advice on how to tune my flink performance. I've tried some configs from the documentation but no luck.

Comment: Why do you assume the jobs fail because of OOM? Maybe I missed something, but I don't see any evidence of that in what you've shared.

Comment: then, whats' the possible cause for this? If I have 55Gb RAM, how's the best practice config for my case? Thanks @DavidAnderson